# Curses.h 's subwin is strange move by mvwin()!

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I use ncurses lib by C. I struct sub win below:

MainWin - sub1 - sub2

```
* = mainwin
# = sub1
' ' = sub2

********************
********************
********************
****##########******
****###   ####******
****###   ####******
****###   ####******
****##########******
********************
********************
********************
********************
```

I move `sub1` by `mvwin(sub1 15, 1)`and redraw. But main win's `sub1` location is not moved and `sub1`'s location is moved. Result I have 2 `sub1`:

```
********************
********************
********************
****##########******
****###   ####******
****###   ####******
****###   ####******
****##########******
********************
********************
********************
*##########*********
*###   ####*********
*###   ####*********
*###   ####*********
*##########*********
********************
********************
```

I think it is copy or afterimage but i notice it is location trouble. I change `sub1`:

```
waddstr(sub1, "i am tired")
```

It changes 2 windows!

I think MainWin's `sub1` location is not updated.

i add test code below:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){
        WINDOW * win;
        WINDOW * win2;
        WINDOW * win3;
        initscr();
        cbreak();

        getch();
        win = newwin(40, 40, 1, 1);
        wbkgd(win, '@');
        wrefresh(win);
        getch();

        win2 = subwin(win, 10, 10, 2, 2);
        wbkgd(win2, '*');
        wrefresh(win2);
        getch();

        win3 = subwin(win2, 5, 5, 3, 3);

        wbkgd(win, '@');
        wrefresh(win);

        doupdate();
        mvwin(win2, 10, 10);
        doupdate();
        touchwin(win2);
        doupdate();
        redrawwin(win2);
        doupdate();
        wrefresh(win2);
        doupdate();
        getch();


        waddstr(win2, "what the fuck");

        redrawwin(win);
        wrefresh(win);
        getch();

        redrawwin(win2);
        wrefresh(win2);
        getch();
        endwin();
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?  If so, perhaps some of your code would be useful?

Comment: The code you provided doesn't match your question at all, and it looks like you've inadvertently duplicated a substantial part of it, so you're wasting everyone's time from the beginning. Other than that, the man page clearly tells you that calling `mvwin()` on sub windows should be avoided.

Comment: oh sorry i mistake copy mycode

Comment: i see that manpage's warning but i need to move subwin. Is there any way to use this feature?

Comment: If you can't get it to work, you can also just recreate the window with the correct position. Also because the man page tells that calling `mvwin()` on sub windows should be avoided.